# Where to set n_job: estimator or GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I often use [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) for hyperparameter tuning. For example, for tuning regularization parameter `C` in [Logistic Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). Whenever an estimator I am using has its own `n_jobs` parameter I am confused where to set it, in estimator or in `GridSearchCV`, or in both? Same thing applies to `cross_validate`.

Comment: @Anwarvic this is not what is asked; question is about a limited number of models which indeed include an `n_jobs` argument, and how it is to be used in conjunction with `GridSearchCV`, which has its own, too.

Comment: I understand. The question is about when the estimator does have this parameter, so does GridSearchCV. Where one should I choose?

Comment: Only time I did a [rough experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61687800/retrieving-specific-classifiers-and-data-from-gridsearchcv/61689871#61689871) with k-nn, turned out that setting this for GridSearchCV only resulted in a *much* faster process. I guess it makes some sense, but don't have the time to elaborate (and that's why I post this just as a comment).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. I don't have a definitive answer, but some elements that are worth mentioning to understand the issue, and don't fir in a comment.

Let's start with why you should or should not use multiprocessing :

- Multiprocessing is useful for independent tasks. This is the case in a GridSearch, where all your different variations of your models are independent.
- Multiprocessing is not useful / make things slower when :

  - Task are too small : creating a new process takes time, and if your task is really small, this overhead with slow the execution of the whole code
  - Too many processes are spawned : your computer have a limited number of cores. If you have more processes than cores, a load balancing mechanism will force the computer to regularly switch the processes that are running. These switches take some time, resulting in a slower execution.

**The first take-out is that you should not use n_jobs in both `GridSearch` and the model you're optimizing, because you will spawn a lot of processes and end up slowing the execution.**

Now, a lot of sklearn models and functions are based on Numpy/SciPy which in turn, are usually implemented in C/Fortran, and thus already use multiprocessing. That means that these should not be used with `n_jobs`>1 set in the `GridSearch`.

If you assume your model is not already parallelized, you can choose to set `n_jobs`at the model level or at the `GridSearch` level. A few models are able to be fully parallelized (`RandomForest` for instance), but most may have at least some part that is sequential (`Boosting` for instance). In the other end, `GridSearch` has no sequential component by design, so it would make sense to set `n_jobs` in `GridSearch` rather than in the model.

That being said, it depend on the implementation of the model, and you can't have a definitive answer without testing for yourself for your case. For example, if you pipeline consume a lot of memory for some reason, setting `n_jobs` in the `GridSearch` may cause memory issues.

As a complement, here is a very interesting [note on parallelism in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#parallelism-resource-management-and-configuration)

Comment: but what if i say if we don't apply n_jobs=-1 in RF it will take a lot of time to run. In that case if we give in both place would it create problem ?